# BuddyPress: bp-core-template-loader.php error blocking access to wp-admin

Tags: errors, buddypress

I just updated WordPress and after doing so received this error:

> ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in
>   /home/tvfilmpa/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-template-loader.php
>   on line 214

Now, I am unable to access the admin panel for my site.

Here is the code for line 214:

```
// Sort
    if ( ! isset( $merged_filters[ $tag ] ) ) {
        ksort( $wp_filter[$tag] );
        $merged_filters[ $tag ] = true;
    }
```

I'm a fish out of water in this scenario, so any help is greatly, greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide any other details. Thank you!

Comment: Have you updated BoddyPress to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in BoddyPress.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-ksort-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array-object-given-in/

You need to update the sort method and wait for the new version.